# Is f(x,y) differentiable at the origin?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My book defines $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ when $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \frac{R_{1,(a,b)} (x,y)}{\|(x,y)-(a,b)\|}=0$ where $R_{1,(a,b)}(x,y)=f(x,y)-L_{(a,b)} (x,y)$ and $L_{(a,b)}(x,y)=f(a,b)+\frac{∂f}{∂x}(x-a)+\frac{∂f}{∂y}(y-b)$

If $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3 +y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=0$ for $(x,y)=(0,0)$, what would $f(x,y)$ be in $R_{1,(0,0)} (x,y)$? Unsure of what to use since it $f(x,y)$ is defined separately.

If I assume $f(x,y)$ is 0, I would get $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{R_{1,(a,b)} (x,y)}{\|(x,y)-(0,0)\|}=\frac{-x-y}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$ which equals $\frac{-\sqrt{2}x}{|x|}$ which is not $0$ when you approach with $y=x$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In limits, the argument is always understood to not equal the point the limit is being taken at. In particular, in your definition of differentiability, the argument $(x,y)$ is never equal to $(a,b)$, which is $(0,0)$ in your problem. Therefore you should use the formula for $f(x,y)$ away from the origin in the definition of $R$. However, note that the definition of $L$ involves evaluating the function at the point in question; so that $f(a,b)$ needs to be $f(0,0)$.